# Alert long message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to set the height of `alert` to display really long messages with enabling scrolling option for messages that extends screen height ?

Help would be appreciated , all plugins are not recommended.

Comment: Are you asking about a JavaScript alert box?

Comment: not without using an html alert facsimile. You can not do anything with native alert other than pass string to it

Comment: You, as a web developer, have precisely 0 (North, Nada, ...) control over the visual aspect of a javascript `alert` message. That's the precise reason why people wrote javascript plugins to mimick it and allow the desired level of control and UI appearance. Unfortunately you explicitly stated that you don't want to use any plugins, so I am afraid you will have to live with what the alert gives you.

Comment: @Phillip yes for sure

Comment: @charlietfl facsimile ? means ?

Comment: Not possible... jQuery dialog would be your best bet!

Comment: @ProllyGeek A simple google search: [*An exact copy or reproduction, as of a document.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/facsimile)

Comment: @malkassem is that the only possible solution ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek No, jQuery dialog is not the only solution. You can also choose to reinvent the wheel and make it from scratch or use one of the 10000 JS/CSS libraries that have made a method that can do this, but you **cannot** do it with the native `alert()` dialog.

Comment: I agree with @h2ooooooo it is the easiest solution...

Comment: can make your own without a lot of effort. Just absolute posiiton div with high `z-index`. Style it any way you want and add a close button

Comment: @charlietfl it would be easier to use a plugin then , i need the original alert for theming issues

Comment: original alert is not used by any plugins...it is avoided for reassons mentioned

Comment: You can also use showModalDialog...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759(v=vs.85).aspx not my preference.

Comment: can i even control font size ?

Comment: The max `alert` let you control is about a poor/awful/ugly format text with `\n`. That's all.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Not in the original alert, but in all the JS/CSS versions you can.

Comment: of course, you are not using native alert, you use html that can be styled in any way you want

Comment: no im asking if i can control native alert font size ?

Comment: if i can use \n why cant i use \t ?

Comment: NO....you haven't paid attention to what everyone said....you can't do anything with it other than pass a string

Comment: here's a really crude alert replacement. Just thrown together quickly  http://jsfiddle.net/m2YRn/1

Answer (score 2):

You can't control a JavaScript `alert` box in anyway.

Modern web development uses a modal dialog box to show this type of information.

jQuery UI `dialog()` is one such popular option.  See here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

[`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) only takes a message and cannot be configured in any way.

I know of no browsers that implement scrolling in the resulting dialog box. Firefox and IE just pop up a modal Windows `MessageBox` in the OS theme's default dialog font, where Chrome has a little piece of toast that pops up towards the top of the browser window.

You would have to use a floating `div` to make a sort of *fake* "dialog box" with the features you want. For example, [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), or the excellent **[alertify](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

Jquery will be best for your criteria

[Jquery Dialog Link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)